# Running Uvicorn through async but reload option isnt working

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, fastapi, uvicorn

I'm trying to run uvicorn with the reload option as you would if you typed "uvicorn app.main:app --reload" in the command line. However, I'm running uvicorn through async as I need to simultaneously run another app (rocketry) though I cant get the reload option to work. Tried adding reload argument in uvicorn to true but still no luck.

```py
class Server(uvicorn.Server):
    """Customized uvicorn.Server
    
    Uvicorn server overrides signals and we need to include
    Rocketry to the signals."""
    def handle_exit(self, sig: int, frame) -> None:
        app_rocketry.session.shut_down()
        return super().handle_exit(sig, frame)


async def main():
    "Run scheduler and the API"
    server = Server(config=uvicorn.Config(app_fastapi, reload=True, workers=1, loop="asyncio"))
    
    api = asyncio.create_task(server.serve())
    sched = asyncio.create_task(app_rocketry.serve())
    
    await asyncio.wait([sched, api])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: You may need to set **`reload=True`** to the `run(...)` function

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem with a similar setup....any solutions found?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is not possible, please refer to the following issue I opened on [Github](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/discussions/1843#discussioncomment-4659163)

The reload option only works using `uvicorn.run()`